# Writing a Windows program to replace several engineering excel spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel, frameworks

I want to write a program for Windows using python and python frameworks (pandas, numpy etc.), which I want to use to replace several engineering excel spreadsheets (which are repetitive). **Please point me in the right direction regarding which python frameworks to use.**

The program should contain and be able to do the following:
- Have a GUI to input variables
- Compute excel formulas using said variables
- Create graphs
- Export information to excel spreadsheets
- Create PDFs

I know I can set up a single excel spreadsheet to do the above, but I'm using this as a way to learn programming...

Comment: My advice: stick to Excel... What you describe is a full application and it will require a good deal of work to produce. You will need to: 1/ carefully design the app including the GUI. 2/ build the GUI (pyQt or pySide could help) 2/ code the data processing part (pandas could help here including for the Excel io) 3/ build the PDF (I do not know the appropriate tool here). Good luck ...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to learn, maybe a less good way to solve the said problem.

GUI - ?

**Matplotlib** can be used for the graphs.

Exporting to excel can be done easily in **pandas** with **df.to_excel()**

**weasyprint** library can be used to export to pdf.